# How to fix 'The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.'?

Tags: php, vps, flutter-web, laravel-8

I am developing a REST service with Laravel 8 to use it on Flutter Web, the API works properly on local using xampp, but not on hosting.

**route/api.php**

```
Route::post('/test', [TestController::class, 'test']);
```

**controllers/API/TestController.php**

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers\API;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class TestController extends BaseController
{
    public function test() {
        return $this->sendResponse([], 'Test!');
    }
}
```

**SOLVED** At least for the setup that I needed, I followed this one:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X4KElZcUi-g&ab_channel=SimplifiedCoding

Comment: Seems like your environments aren't the same. How is the route registered locally and how is it registered live?

Comment: I am a beginner at this so please bear with me, what I did locally is that I put the whole laravel project inside xampp/htdocs and move the project's public folder in htdocs also. In the live server, I uploaded the laravel project just outside the public_html, and move the project's public folder inside the public_html, and updated the index.php's directory of autoload and bootstrap. If that's what you mean..

Comment: the website content is also in public_html which is flutter web

Comment: is there some configuration I should check? the laravel 8's requirements are all good from php version up to the installed php extensions

Comment: is running XAMPP in live server too?

Answer (score 0):

1. Do you need the '/' before test in route definition?
   `Route::post('/test', [TestController::class, 'test']);`
2. Routes work by using pattern matching. Are you sure you do not have any routes that is overriding or has precedence over this one?
3. Have you tried clearing your cache?

   `php artisan route:cache`
4. You can also view active routes in Laravel

   `php artisan route:list`

Comment: 1. I did tried to remove '/' but the result are still the same, for both local and live.. local's good and live is not.
2. I just made that api to easily replicate what I am experiencing with login api.

Comment: 3. I always do the clearing of cache with `php artisan optimize` both local and live whenever I upload a new files live or made an update locally

though when I try to execute a route with a middleware of `auth:api` in the live server, the response is `Route [login] not defined`, is it an indication that somehow it got a connection?

Comment: 4. both local and live got the same output, except for the **Name** Column, the generated part is different.

Thank you for spending some time in this topic.